# What is the typescript type of a constructor function?

Tags: typescript

What is the Typescript type of a constructor function?

Here is an example of what I mean which throws this warning:

`TS2507: Type 'Function' is not a constructor function type.`

What type do I need to define `clazz` as here ?

```
class A {
 foo() {console.log("bar")};
}

console.log(typeof A);
// function

function Factory(clazz: Function) : any {
    class B extends clazz {
        // Type 'Function' is not a constructor function type.
    }
    return B;
}

class Foo extends Factory(A) {}

new Foo().foo();
```

If I suppress the TS warning this code will execute and print out the expected result of `bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures):

```
type Constructable = { new (...args: any[]): any; };

function Factory(clazz: Constructable): Constructable { 
    class B extends clazz {

    }
    return B;
}
```

But this is not very good as a return type. Ideally it should at least return the class that was passed in:

```
function Factory<T extends Constructable>(clazz: T): T {
    class B extends clazz {

    }
    return B;
}
```

Going further, we could also annotate the return type as `T & { ... }` to match the class that is returned, too.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGwCGAjAG2gF4oBvKBCAdygAoA6JnVAcyQC4ocEQBtALoBKLjxABuKAF9xAKFkAzdAmwBLRFABiObHFQgAPABUoEAB7AICACZJYiFBmz4iAPjqYCOAF7euRkSgTCgB6EO4EBDhcYHUESmjKCAhrFNkoDKhPHCQ7ACFTCytbLK9fcnlM6XTM1AhgdFR4vLkpeWzcqABBcjbZDvzCyxs7bV19Oi6hXqA)

Comment: That works great. This type seems so basic it should be included in TS itself.

Comment: any solution to this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGwCGAjAG2gF4oBvKBCAdygAoA6JnVAcyQC4ocEQBtALoBKLjxABuKAF9xAKFmYCOJEigBBMlPlFg3KKSq01dIXNk6omRCgzZ8RLvGRosuQiW4Mrz28DipxIA

Comment: Thats a constructor function not an object with a construct signature

Comment: I need to do a equality check on the two like this. Could just casting the constructor function to a Constructable cause any issues? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGwCGAjAG2gF4oBvKBCAdygAoA6JnVAcyQC4ocEQBtALoBKLjxABuKAF9xAKFmYCOJEigBBMlPlFg3KKSq01dIXNk6omLvGRosuQiXVnMiJHCIMCcVnUz7iUhwGV1sMbDhUIXkAM3QEbABLREs4AFswFgg6HGs3O2x8IgAaKDw8sPsiiCFyWSgG1OQPCC8fHIDSPGitBXTM1Gy1UuDQlHDgSO5VG3Gqx1N5VwysumHuEPyJyNMgA

Comment: I don't think so but with casting you have to be super sure if the cast is safe.